# Error Handling with Reqwest and Axum handlers?

Tags: rust, reqwest, rust-axum

What's the correct/proper method for error handling using `reqwest` to call an external API in an Axum handler?

Using the `?` operator to try and handle errors, as in the Reqwest docs, causes the compiler to throw an error because my handler is no longer a valid Axum handler.

But without using `?`, even if the external API returns an error (e.g. receiving a `400`), I end up in the `Ok` branch of my `match`, causing the status codes from my API to always be `200`.

How can I refactor the following code to properly handle errors coming back from the external API, return JSON responses, and produce a valid Axum handler, so that when a user makes a bad request my API responds with a proper status code, as well?

```rust
async fn get_weather(
    location_query: Query<WeatherQuery>,
) -> Result<Json<serde_json::Value>, Json<serde_json::Value>> {
    let location_query = &location_query.location;
    let key = std::env::var("WEATHER_STACK_API_KEY").unwrap();
    let request_url = format!(
        "http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key={}&query={}&units=f",
        key, location_query
    );
    let res = reqwest::get(request_url).await;
    println!("res: {:?}", res);
    match res {
        // the response from the reqwest::get() call is always ok, even if the user
        // makes a bad request (e.g. "?location=asdf1234")
        // since I need to handle that response here, my API is always returning 200
        Ok(response) => {
            let res_json = response.json::<Weather>().await;
            match res_json {
                Ok(res) => Ok(Json(serde_json::json!({
                    "data": res,
                    "success": true
                }))),
                Err(_e) => Err(Json(serde_json::json!({
                    "error": {
                        "message": "Request to Weather Stack Failed!",
                    },
                    "success": false
                }))),
            }
        }
        Err(_e) => Err(Json(serde_json::json!({
            "error": {
                "message": "Internal Server Error. Request failed.",
            },
            "success": false
        }))),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably convert most errors from any failable function to [anyhow Error](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/index.html) and then use it in your main handler. There is even an [example](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/main/examples/anyhow-error-response/src/main.rs) in axum repository that might be a useful consideration.

Comment: Ah, okay. So by “use it in your main function” do you mean writing an additional function to handle the `reqwest::get` call and then call that in the main `get_weather` handler?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Your suggestion was exactly what I needed to solve the problem! Thank you.